# java display problem in Scilab 6.0.1 and Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, java

I just installed Sclilab 6.0.1 from Synaptic on my Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
When I want to use the plot or plot2D functions, the graphical window that opens is totally white (and the icons above only appear if the mouse hovers over them).

[image]

I think it is a hardware problem with my graphic card but I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Can you help me?

My PC is an old Sony Vaio SVE1512E6EW :

to NOrbert (only graphics):

```
phil@phil-SVE1512E6EW-Blanc:~$ lspci -k
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500/6600 / 6700M Series]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Turks HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500/6600 / 6700M Series]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
...
```

Then I tried your test,and got lots of lines, but no plot in Scilab (blank window again)  :

```
phil@phil-SVE1512E6EW-Blanc:~$ LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 scilab -e "plot(1:10);"
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.class.path=/usr/share/java/flexdock.jar:/usr/share/java/skinlf.jar:/usr/share/java/looks.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/jhall.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-queryparser-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/maven-repo/org/freehep/freehep-util/debian/freehep-util-debian.jar:/usr/share/maven-repo/org/freehep/freehep-io/debian/freehep-io-debian.jar:/usr/share/maven-repo/org/freehep/freehep-graphicsio/debian/freehep-graphicsio-debian.jar:/usr/share/java/freehep-graphicsio-emf-2.1.jar:/usr/share/java/freehep-graphics2d-2.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/jrosetta-API.jar:/usr/share/java/jrosetta-engine-1.0.4.jar:/usr/share/java/jgraphx.jar:/usr/share/java/jogl2.jar:/usr/share/java/gluegen2-rt.jar:/usr/share/java/jeuclid-core.jar:/usr/share/java/jlatexmath-fop-1.0.7.jar:/usr/share/java/fop.jar:/usr/share/java/saxon.jar:/usr/share/java/batik.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-apis-ext.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-io.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlgraphics-commons.jar:/usr/share/java/avalon-framework.jar:/usr/share/java/jlatexmath-1.0.7.jar:/usr/share/java/ecj.jar:/usr/share/java/javax.activation.jar:/usr/share/java/jaxb-runtime.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/gui/jar/org.scilab.modules.gui.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/action_binding/jar/org.scilab.modules.action_binding.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/scinotes/jar/org.scilab.modules.scinotes.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/renderer/jar/org.scilab.modules.renderer.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/javasci/jar/org.scilab.modules.javasci.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/jvm/jar/org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/history_browser/jar/org.scilab.modules.history_browser.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/core/jar/org.scilab.modules.core.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/xcos/jar/org.scilab.modules.xcos.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/ui_data/jar/org.scilab.modules.ui_data.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/history_manager/jar/org.scilab.modules.history_manager.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/scirenderer/jar/scirenderer.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/graphic_export/jar/org.scilab.modules.graphic_export.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/graphic_objects/jar/org.scilab.modules.graphic_objects.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/external_objects_java/jar/org.scilab.modules.external_objects_java.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/console/jar/org.scilab.modules.console.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/localization/jar/org.scilab.modules.localization.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/graph/jar/org.scilab.modules.graph.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/completion/jar/org.scilab.modules.completion.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/commons/jar/org.scilab.modules.commons.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/preferences/jar/org.scilab.modules.preferences.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/types/jar/org.scilab.modules.types.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_en_US_help.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/org.scilab.modules.helptools.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_fr_FR_help.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_ru_RU_help.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_images.jar:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath (file:/usr/share/scilab/modules/jvm/jar/org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.sys_paths
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.scilab.modules.jvm.LibraryPath
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL3bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0.0, unitID 0, handle 0x7ff1e4502d60, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x1720f0f0, isOwner true, <49f01e4d, f5fc49c>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL3.sw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:737)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at org.scilab.modules.gui.bridge.tab.SwingScilabDockablePanel.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at org.flexdock.docking.defaults.DefaultDockingPort.paint(DefaultDockingPort.java:1983)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:246)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2002)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3940)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1890)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL3bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0.0, unitID 0, handle 0x7ff1e4502d60, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x1720f0f0, isOwner true, <49f01e4d, f5fc49c>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL3.sw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.verifyInstance(GLContextImpl.java:1471)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.setGLFunctionAvailability(GLContextImpl.java:1942)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXContext.createImpl(X11GLXContext.java:395)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrentWithinLock(GLContextImpl.java:765)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:648)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:586)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1731)
    ... 55 more
Exception in thread "Thread-3" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.display(GLJPanel.java:465)
    at org.scilab.modules.gui.bridge.canvas.SwingScilabCanvasImpl$SafeGLJPanel.display(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.forge.scirenderer.implementation.jogl.JoGLCanvas$CanvasAnimator.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1367)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1342)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.display(GLJPanel.java:463)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL3bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0.0, unitID 0, handle 0x7ff1e4502d60, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x349dd0e8, isOwner true, <5ee54fb1, 6470c835>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL3.sw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:246)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$12.run(GLJPanel.java:1535)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL3bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0.0, unitID 0, handle 0x7ff1e4502d60, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x349dd0e8, isOwner true, <5ee54fb1, 6470c835>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL3.sw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.verifyInstance(GLContextImpl.java:1471)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.setGLFunctionAvailability(GLContextImpl.java:1942)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXContext.createImpl(X11GLXContext.java:395)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrentWithinLock(GLContextImpl.java:765)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:648)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:586)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1731)
    ... 27 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: Profile GL3bc is not available on X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0.0, unitID 0, handle 0x7ff1e4502d60, owner true, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x26657682, isOwner true, <3f8a0a47, 53c47f74>[count 1, qsz 0, owner <AWT-EventQueue-0>]]], but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.sw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.sw], GLProfile[GL3/GL3.sw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL3.sw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.initialize(GLJPanel.java:1795)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.initializeBackendImpl(GLJPanel.java:1377)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.paintComponent(GLJPanel.java:549)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:737)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at org.scilab.modules.gui.bridge.tab.SwingScilabDockablePanel.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at org.flexdock.docking.defaults.DefaultDockingPort.paint(DefaultDockingPort.java:1983)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:246)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2002)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3940)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1890)
```

...

```
phil@phil-SVE1512E6EW-Blanc:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 19.2.8 for AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.3.0-45-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

2020-04-09 update : Finally I solved the problem by finding a proprietary AMD Radeon driver from the AMD website : https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-20

Comment: Seems to be graphic driver issue. Please add output of `lspci -k` to the question. Do you see plots when run `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 scilab -e "plot(1:10);"`?

Comment: Please install two additional packages by `sudo apt-get install vainfo mesa-va-drivers`, reboot and add output of the `vainfo` info command to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1223962/edit).

Comment: Looks like the drivers are correct, do you see any plots while running `scilab -e "plot(1:10);"`?

Comment: No, blank window again...

Comment: I'll check the laptop with AMD graphics and 18.04 LTS some hours later. As a workaround you can try to run binary Scilab 5.5.2 downloaded from [official site](https://www.scilab.org/download/5.5.2). Simply extract it and run *scilab* executable from extracted *bin* folder.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this : "~$ '/home/phil/Téléchargements/scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-x86_64/scilab-5.5.2/bin/scilab'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
"

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by finding a proprietary AMD Radeon driver from the AMD website : https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-20.
I copied this at the end of my initial post, but is there any TAG like "Solved"  to put in my subject ? I don't find the information...

Comment: Great! You can answer your answer by clicking special button at the bottom .

Comment: but I have a new problem : after rebooting, the second monitor (plugged in the VGA plug)  is not detected  anymore... Can you help me ? I am lost !

Comment: Usually such problems are solved by setting monitor configuration in control center (`xfce4-display-settings` component).

Comment: I know but only the monitor of my laptop appears in the list (and the external monitor is well connected to the VGA  plug. The external monitor worked with the new driver before rebooting.

Comment: NOrbert, have you an idea how I could go back to the previous config ? I uninstalled the proprietary AMD Radeon driver, but my external monitor is still not detected (and it is detected under Win10), thus no connection problem). 
I need absolutely my external monitor, thus how can I go back to the old driver ? Thanks,

Comment: I do not have any AMD/ATI devices near me, so I do not know their specifics and can't check this. I can recommend reading the docs somewhere like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI .

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by using the code `flatpak install flathub org.scilab.Scilab` after that use `flatpak run org.scilab.Scilab`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1214714)

Comment: @David, I changed it!